# 各行の文字列のユニークな個数をカウントする方法

Tags: emeditor

テキストをA→Z順に並び替えたうえで、重複なしで文字列と個数を表示させるマクロはありますでしょうか。

いうえ
あ
あい
いうえ
あ
いうえ

たとえば上記から、下記の結果を得たいのです。

あ   2
あい  1
いうえ 3

ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[検索] メニューの [頻出文字列を抽出] を選択して、既定のオプションのままで OK をクリックすれば可能です。出力結果は必要に応じて並べ替えてください。

マクロだと、以下のようになります。

```
document.selection.ExtractFrequent(eeFreqTypeLines, eeFindReplaceCase, 1, 100, "");
document.Sort("1>A+",eeSortBinaryComparison | eeSortIgnorePrefix,"");
```

Comment: [頻出文字列を抽出]で望む結果が得られました。重宝いたします。